How to announce a text, without focusing on it?
So I'm working on an accessibility feature.
My task is to announce an error message, which appears right after I click the submit button.
Other than that, the error message can not get a focus, so the focus stays on the button while the talkback reads the error message.
I'm not sure if it is possible.
@Composable
fun Feature(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var isError = false

    if (isError) {
        Column {
            Text(text = "Error message to be announced")
        }
    }

    Button(modifier = Modifier.semantics {
        contentDescription = "Submit button "
    },
        onClick = { isError = true }) {
        Text(text = "Submit")
    }
}

It is a very simple example, how the UI looks like now.
Okay, so I found the LiveRegionMode feature in compose, which does mostly what I want. Unfortunately it works only just the first time.
Text(
     text = "state.value",
     modifier = Modifier
          .focusable()
          .clearAndSetSemantics {
              this.contentDescription = state.value
              liveRegion = LiveRegionMode.Polite
           }
    )
 }

Button(onClick = { state.value = "${Math.random().toInt()} value" }) {
    Text(text = "Click me")
}

I read that, it will announce the string, only when something change, when I click the button for the first time, it reads the text as expected, but second time it doesn't. The text changes, because of the random generator.

I think I found the soliton, but it doesn't come from compose.
View.announceForAccessibility() does exactly what I want.
val localView = LocalView.current

LaunchedEffect(isSubmitButtonClicked) {
     if (isSubmitButtonClicked.value) {
           isSubmitButtonClicked.value = false
           localView.announceForAccessibility(errorTextContentDescription)
     }
}

